# Determine if the set $A= \{(x,y) \mid |y|\leqslant|x|, x \ne 0\}$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

> Determine if the set $A= \{(x,y) \mid |y|\leqslant|x|, x \ne 0\}$ is closed?

I know that $A$ is closed if $A^c$ is open. Now $A^c$ is just $A^c = \{(x,y) \mid |y| >|x| \}$. To show that $A^c$ is open I would have to show that for every $x \in A^c$ there is a disk $B(x,r) \subset A^c$, but I'm not sure how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $A^{c}=\{(x,y): |y|>|x|\} \cup \{(0,y): y \in \mathbb R\}$.

$A$ is not closed: $(0,0) \in A^{c}$ and every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ contains points with $|y|\leq |x|$.

[Given a ball of radius $r$ around the origin consider the point $(\frac 1 4 r,\frac 1 2 r)$].

Comment: The condition $x \ne 0$ doesn't affect $A^c$?

Comment: It surely does. $A^{c}=\{(x,y): |y|>|x|\} \cup \{(0,y): y \in \mathbb R\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$x\ne 0$ screams at me that $(0,0)$ will be a limit point.

And indeed for every $r$ will be points $(x,y)$ so that $|y|\le |x|$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < r$.  For example $p= (\frac 1{\sqrt 2}r, \frac 1{\sqrt 2}r)\in A$ and $d(p,(0,0)) = \frac 12 r < r$.

So $(0,0)$ is a limit point of $A$ that is not in $A$.  SO $A$ is not closed as it doesn't contain all its limit points.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

Let the sequence $((x_n,y_n))$ be defined by $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,1/n).$ Then $((x_n,y_n))$ is a convergent sequence in $A$ with limit $(0,0)$. But $(0,0) \notin A.$ Hence $A$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\neq 0$, we have $(x,0) \in A$, thus, $B =\mathbb R \times \{0\}\cap A = \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\times \{0\}$, and $\overline B = \mathbb R \times \{0\}$ so $B$ is not closed. But, $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ is closed, so $A$ must not be closed.